# Unable to install QUCS (Quite Universal Circuit Software) on ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: software-installation

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qucs
[sudo] password for hsthakar: 
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~qucs/ubuntu/ppa'.
ERROR: '~qucs' user or team does not exist.

$ sudo apt-get install qucs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package qucs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qucs' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: The [mentioned PPA](https://launchpad.net/~qucs/+archive/ubuntu/qucs) doesn't support 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

[Qucs](http://qucs.sourceforge.net/install.html) does not support Ubuntu 15.10.

On top of that if you'd like to install it on earlier version you should replace:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qucs
```

With:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:qucs/qucs
```